# use JavaFx Application in swing project

Tags: java, swing, awt, javafx-2, javafx

I have to browse Html files in java windows application software . For it i am using JEditorPane control but its not supporting some tags of HTML and formatting is disturbing in JEditorPane. I have searched on net and net is suggesting me to use JavaFXApplication control for it . In C# there is a control WebBrowser that displays the html file in the same format easily . Is it possible in java too to display the html files with all supporting  tags .
Can you suggest me the control or something wrong in my  code.I am using the following code.

```
 try
 { 
  File htmlfile= new File("path of the html file");
  JEditorPane htmlPane= new JEditorPane();
  htmlPane.setEditable(false);
  htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
  htmlPane.setPage(htmlfile.toURI().toURL());
  JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(htmlPane);
  add(jsp);
  }

  catch(Exception ex)
   {


    }
```

Comment: http://www.a1o1.com/java-fx20-embedding-webview-in-swing

Comment: As a general tip:  `catch(Exception ex)
   {


    }`  Don't put 2 white space lines just to ignore an error.  Change that to `catch(Exception ex)
   { ex.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: thanks andrew i will take care about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to view the HTML SOURCE and not trying to implement a web browser.

If that's the case you can use JavaFX's HTML editor **assuming you are using Java 6 with JavaFX OR Java 7 which includes JavaFX**

Here's a short sample of using the javafx package using the [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) and [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html):

```
public class JavaFXDemo {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HTML Editor");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
                Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor);
                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```